# meaning of 'buzz one's door'

Tags: meaning

> He was ***buzzing my door***.

I googled 'buzz the door' and it says it means 'To remotely and electronically unlock a door for someone'.
But the speaker didn't mean that.

So, maybe '***buzz one's door***' means 'unexpectedly drop by one's house'?

(My native language is not English. Please be kind to me. :-))

Comment: Pushing the doorbell (which in this case is a buzzer).

Comment: Thank you! It helped!

Comment: Hi Lily, I think you really should check out our sister site http://ell.stackexchange.com I think you’d find that a lot of your questions fit better there.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'll check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to buzz  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25496?rskey=rlYcZD&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> to phone or signal (a call or message) by the ‘buzzer’

In this case, it is similar to ringing a doorbell.  Likely, one is signalling your door, wanting attention.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot!